# Можно ли передать данные intent-ом из FragmentActivity в DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Каждый день недели это DialogFragment (в данном случае, `fmonday`), при нажатии на кнопку появляется другой DialogFragment со спиннером (`AlertDFragment`).

При выборе предмета в диалоге `AlertDFragment`, нужно передать оттуда 3 `String`-переменных в `fmonday`.

Как передать данные из одного диалогфрагмента в другой? Передать обычным интентом не получается, т.к. ни один из них не является Activity.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

у `AlertDialog` есть `Listener` на действие, с его помощью вы можете передать данные в `Actvitiy`. В `Activity` у вас есть ссылка на fmonday. Сделайте любой метод у `fmonday`, который и будет принимать данные. Передайте данные, полученные из `AlertDialog` в `fmonday` через этот метод

Comment: немного не понял насчет метода, можно чуть больше подробностей?